# Case with condition in select returning null

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a small issue with using the CASE statement with condition. Basically this is my code:

```
SELECT m.codmagazzino as Magazzino, m.integratore, i.nomeintegratore, 
m.scadenza, m.quantita,
CASE m.scadenza
when (m.scadenza <= curdate() + interval 1 month) then '50%'
when (m.scadenza >= curdate() + interval 1 month) AND (m.scadenza <= 
curdate() + interval 2 month) then '30%'
when (m.scadenza >= curdate() + interval 2 month) AND (m.scadenza <= 
curdate() + interval 3 month) then '10%'
END AS ScontoSuggerito 

FROM magazzino m INNER JOIN integratori i on m.integratore = 
i.codintegratore
order by scadenza
;
```

what I want it to do is to check the expiry date (scadenza), and the sooner it expires, the greater will be the suggested discount (ScontoSuggerito). The problem is that it gives me null although there are rows that fall into the condition in the CASE statement.

```
                        Scadenza
2   3   Creatina Mono   2017-11-03  12  
2   5   MaxPower        2017-11-07  6   
2   9   ImpactWhey      2017-11-24  11  
2   4   Omega 3         2017-11-30  5   
1   1   IsoWhey         2018-02-17  10
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should at least include the data which is causing the problem.  How can we read your mind?

Comment: Also, the start and end points of your intervals all overlap.  Not necessarily a problem, but you should be aware of this.

Comment: syntax issue? remove `m.scadenze` after case?  `case when condition then result1 when  condition2 then result2 when condition3 thenresult 3 end`

Comment: i had to include it becase there's a "scadenza" column in both integratori and magazzino, and it gave me an error regarding the ambiguity

Comment: I'm saying try changing this line `CASE m.scadenza` to this `CASE`  you seem to be mixing the two different case patterns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly just a syntax issue:  There are two patterns when using case statements:  you seemed to be trying to use both; when only one can be applied.

DOCS:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

One pattern starts out `case variable when valueA then ResultA when valueB then ResultB end`

The other goes `Case when OptionalCompoundCondition(s) then ResultA when ConditionsB then ResultB End`

The former compares 1 value to 1 value; the latter allows for compound conditions.

```
SELECT m.codmagazzino as Magazzino
     , m.integratore
     , i.nomeintegratore
     , m.scadenza
     , m.quantita
     , CASE when (m.scadenza <= curdate() + interval 1 month) then '50%'
            when (m.scadenza >= curdate() + interval 1 month) AND (m.scadenza <= curdate() + interval 2 month) then '30%'
            when (m.scadenza >= curdate() + interval 2 month) AND (m.scadenza <= curdate() + interval 3 month) then '10%'
       END AS ScontoSuggerito 
FROM magazzino m 
INNER JOIN integratori i 
   on m.integratore = i.codintegratore
order by scadenza;
```

Comment: Thanks! So "m.scadenza" right after case wasn't needed. I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks again mate

Comment: Well it depends on which pattern your using.  If you're using a simple comparison of 1 value to 1 value then you can use the case field when 'A' then when 'B' then end approach..  If however you have COMPOUND conditions and not a straight equality check, then you have to use the `CASE WHEN` approach instead.  to be honest I always use the case when as I generally never seem to need just a straight equality check.